# Alpine.js is not working in new Laravel and Vite instance

Tags: javascript, laravel, vite, alpine.js

I started a new Laravel project and now Laravel Mix has been replaced with Vite.

I've installed Alpine.js and launched it in the bootstrap.js file but, Alpine.js not recognized in the Laravel blade files and the other JS files.

**vite.config**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import  path from "path";
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),
    ],
    resolve:{
        alias:{
            '~alpine':path.resolve(__dirname,'node_modules/alpinejs'),
        }
    }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjTVH.png)

**app.js**

```
import './bootstrap';
import alpine from "./alpinejs/src/alpine";
console.log(alpine.version);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjTVH.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I add Alpine like the following.

**bootstrap.js**

```
import _ from 'lodash';
window._ = _;

import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = window.$ = $

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
window.Alpine = Alpine;
Alpine.start();
```